# Parameterizing Objects in spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a problem with parameterizations of list of object by using spock where block. It seems the ListInput value is not taking from the where clause and always coming null value. I have verified the same feature for string and other primitive types and it is working fine.
Does Spock support parameterizations objects ? If yes what is the issue here .

```
 def "check Param Of List of Objects"()
 {

        expect:
        def a= hasflag(ListInput);
        a== flag
        where:
        ListInput | flag
        BOList1  | true
        BOList2  | false
 }
```

Here the type of BOList1   is an java ArrayList contains the  object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough information for a definitive answer but I'll try to help.

The where block isn't exactly just a block of code, it's more like a number of parameters passed to a method. It *can* do a lot, but sometimes you need to pass your code a little differently.

Of note:
 - Void methods aren't allowed (but you can get around this using .with{} )
 - An iterative parameter cannot also be a derived parameter (constructed from other parameters)
 - If you're referencing class level variables (defined within the class but outside this test) they need to be given the @Shared annotation for your tests to have access.

Given more information about where your lists are coming from will help me give better advice.

---

Final tip; explicitly typecast your parameters to see if that gives you anymore information

```
def "check Param Of List of Objects"(ArrayList listInput, boolean flag) {
    expect:
        flag == hasflag(ListInput);
    where:
        listInput | flag
         BOList1  | true
         BOList2  | false
}
```

Comment: .I have annotated all the reference variable with "@Shared" and its worked for me. I was using static class variable for the list which has reference in outside the test.But even for static reference it is working when am not using where block ie  by directly passing the list into hasflag(BOList1 ) . Any way it is working fine now. Thanks